# Problem when baking texture use python script

Tags: python, texture-baking, baking

I am trying to bake the Mix Shader Texture and output it as an image. Here is the original object

[image]

I use this code.

```
import bpy
bpy.data.scenes[0].render.engine = "CYCLES"

# Set the device_type
bpy.context.preferences.addons[
    "cycles"
].preferences.compute_device_type = "CUDA" # or "OPENCL"

# Set the device and feature set
bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = "GPU"

# get_devices() to let Blender detects GPU device
bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.get_devices()
print(bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.compute_device_type)
for d in bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.devices:
    d["use"] = 1 # Using all devices, include GPU and CPU
    print(d["name"], d["use"])
    

    
obj = bpy.context.active_object
image_name = obj.name + '_BakedTexture'
img = bpy.data.images.new(image_name,512,512)
for mat in obj.data.materials:

    mat.use_nodes = True #Here it is assumed that the materials have been created with nodes, otherwise it would not be possible to assign a node for the Bake, so this step is a bit useless
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    texture_node =nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
    texture_node.name = 'Bake_node'
    texture_node.select = True
    nodes.active = texture_node
    texture_node.image = img #Assign the image to the node

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.bake(type='DIFFUSE', save_mode='EXTERNAL')

img.save_render(filepath='C:\\TEMP\\baked.png')

for mat in obj.data.materials:
    for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if n.name == 'Bake_node':
            mat.node_tree.nodes.remove(n)
```

However, the output is pretty strange:

[image]

Can someone pls tell me what is going on? Why it looks so dark?

Thanks!

Link to the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13J2Us042Ic0nXyFtDXT0anJgBzJy9xnA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: provide the blend file

Comment: hi, here is the Link to the project [Shell](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13J2Us042Ic0nXyFtDXT0anJgBzJy9xnA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AB24ITZHtuE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `pass_filter={'COLOR'}`

```py
import bpy
bpy.data.scenes[0].render.engine = "CYCLES"

# Set the device_type
bpy.context.preferences.addons[
    "cycles"
].preferences.compute_device_type = "CUDA" # or "OPENCL"

# Set the device and feature set
bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = "GPU"

# get_devices() to let Blender detects GPU device
bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.get_devices()
print(bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.compute_device_type)
for d in bpy.context.preferences.addons["cycles"].preferences.devices:
    d["use"] = 1 # Using all devices, include GPU and CPU
    print(d["name"], d["use"])
    

    
obj = bpy.context.active_object
image_name = obj.name + '_BakedTexture'
img = bpy.data.images.new(image_name,512,512)
for mat in obj.data.materials:

    mat.use_nodes = True #Here it is assumed that the materials have been created with nodes, otherwise it would not be possible to assign a node for the Bake, so this step is a bit useless
    nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
    texture_node =nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
    texture_node.name = 'Bake_node'
    texture_node.select = True
    nodes.active = texture_node
    texture_node.image = img #Assign the image to the node

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.ops.object.bake('INVOKE_DEFAULT', type='DIFFUSE', pass_filter={'COLOR'}, save_mode='EXTERNAL')

img.save_render(filepath='C:\\TEMP\\baked.png')

for mat in obj.data.materials:
    for n in mat.node_tree.nodes:
        if n.name == 'Bake_node':
            mat.node_tree.nodes.remove(n)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. However, the second used image is not baked. Can you pls check the project file I uploaded? 
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I used two BSDF and then used a Mix Shader to combine them to generate a rust feeling. Maybe the problem is due to the Mix Shader?

Comment: It may be the order in which yo mixed the components, or if you have a Bump node in the stack, that can interfere with the way it bakes normals.